# Running Node.js with Forever

Tags: raspbian, node.js

I have installed Node.js and Forever in my Raspberry Pi but I somehow don't know how to get Forever to start my `hello.js` which is in the `/node/` directory. I followed the tutorial, [Run NodeJS server on boot with Forever on Raspberry Pi](http://www.linuxcircle.com/2013/12/30/run-nodejs-server-on-boot-with-forever-on-raspberry-pi/) but cannot get it to work

1. I cannot find `/var/www/` in my Raspberry Pi, as Forever seems to look for it to start any file.
2. if I `cd /node/` then run `forever start hello.js`, it will work.

How can I do something like below?

```
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /usr/local/bin/forever start /node/hello.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how this work. It is because of root directory. In my `raspberry pi 3b`, the root directory is `/home/pi/`. So in my case, the whole script will be:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /usr/local/bin/forever start /home/pi/node/hello.js
```

then it works.